# EMF Tree View Load Resource Hook

Tags: eclipse, resources, hook, emf, ecore

I want to execute code and/or change the implementation of the "Load Resource..." context menu option (see pictures below) in the default tree view for ecore model instances. What part of the code executes when a resource is imported, where can I hook into it?

The "Load Resource..." context menu option for an instance of a model backed by an ecore model:

[image: The "Load Resource..." context menu option for an instance of a model backed by an ecore model]

The windows that opens to load a resource (another model instance):

[image: The windows that opens to load a resource (another model instance)]

Comment: Cloud you try this one [Link1](https://www.eclipse.org/emf-parsley/documentation.html) and [Link2](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/637914/).

Comment: @A.Raza I'm using Sirius, Link 1 may look nice, but it's not as smooth as simply using the generated editor. I fail to see how Link 2 applies to my case.